# python scikit-learn clustering with missing data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, missing-data

I want to cluster data with missing columns. Doing it manually I would calculate the distance in case of a missing column simply without this column.

With scikit-learn, missing data is not possible. There is also no chance to specify a user distance function.

Is there any chance to cluster with missing data?

Example data:

```
n_samples = 1500
noise = 0.05  
X, _ = make_swiss_roll(n_samples, noise)

rnd = np.random.rand(X.shape[0],X.shape[1]) 
X[rnd<0.1] = np.nan
```

Comment: I guess you could handle missing data by assigning them a specific value. Usually, the median or the mean is taken as a replacement. This may seem weirds, but it's actually quite standard. Would that seem like an acceptable solution?

Comment: I'd like to avoid assigning e.g. a global mean value, since this might destroy a proper class assignement. In fact, I'd like to use the clustering for imputation, i.e assigning the cluster mean to the missing values instead of global mean.

Comment: How do you calculate a distance with a missing value? The missing value can be anything, so your distance can be way off. You should input missing values either by a mean or by correlation with other variables.

Comment: Hmmm ... good question. I think about calculating a kind normalized gaussian distance, i.e. (sum of absolue distance of components) divided by (sum of sum of components). This can be done with all columns or only with the available columns. Is this a bad idea? I think of e.g. naive bayes classifier where I also can 'skip' missing columns.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think you can use an iterative EM-type algorithm:

> Initialize missing values to their column means
>
> Repeat until convergence:
>
> - Perform K-means clustering on the filled-in data
> - Set the missing values to the centroid coordinates of the clusters to which they were assigned

### Implementation

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def kmeans_missing(X, n_clusters, max_iter=10):
    """Perform K-Means clustering on data with missing values.

    Args:
      X: An [n_samples, n_features] array of data to cluster.
      n_clusters: Number of clusters to form.
      max_iter: Maximum number of EM iterations to perform.

    Returns:
      labels: An [n_samples] vector of integer labels.
      centroids: An [n_clusters, n_features] array of cluster centroids.
      X_hat: Copy of X with the missing values filled in.
    """

    # Initialize missing values to their column means
    missing = ~np.isfinite(X)
    mu = np.nanmean(X, 0, keepdims=1)
    X_hat = np.where(missing, mu, X)

    for i in xrange(max_iter):
        if i > 0:
            # initialize KMeans with the previous set of centroids. this is much
            # faster and makes it easier to check convergence (since labels
            # won't be permuted on every iteration), but might be more prone to
            # getting stuck in local minima.
            cls = KMeans(n_clusters, init=prev_centroids)
        else:
            # do multiple random initializations in parallel
            cls = KMeans(n_clusters, n_jobs=-1)

        # perform clustering on the filled-in data
        labels = cls.fit_predict(X_hat)
        centroids = cls.cluster_centers_

        # fill in the missing values based on their cluster centroids
        X_hat[missing] = centroids[labels][missing]

        # when the labels have stopped changing then we have converged
        if i > 0 and np.all(labels == prev_labels):
            break

        prev_labels = labels
        prev_centroids = cls.cluster_centers_

    return labels, centroids, X_hat
```

### Example with fake data

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def make_fake_data(fraction_missing, n_clusters=5, n_samples=1500,
                   n_features=3, seed=None):
    # complete data
    gen = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    X, true_labels = make_blobs(n_samples, n_features, n_clusters,
                                random_state=gen)
    # with missing values
    missing = gen.rand(*X.shape) < fraction_missing
    Xm = np.where(missing, np.nan, X)
    return X, true_labels, Xm


X, true_labels, Xm = make_fake_data(fraction_missing=0.3, n_clusters=5, seed=0)
labels, centroids, X_hat = kmeans_missing(Xm, n_clusters=5)

# plot the inferred points, color-coded according to the true cluster labels
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, subplot_kw={'projection':'3d', 'aspect':'equal'})
ax[0].scatter3D(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], c=true_labels, cmap='gist_rainbow')
ax[1].scatter3D(X_hat[:, 0], X_hat[:, 1], X_hat[:, 2], c=true_labels,
                cmap='gist_rainbow')
ax[0].set_title('Original data')
ax[1].set_title('Imputed (30% missing values)')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

### Benchmark

To assess the algorithm's performance, we can use the [adjusted mutual information](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mutual-information-based-scores) between the true and inferred cluster labels. A score of 1 is perfect performance and 0 represents chance:

```
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_mutual_info_score

fraction = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.05)
n_repeat = 10
scores = np.empty((2, fraction.shape[0], n_repeat))
for i, frac in enumerate(fraction):
    for j in range(n_repeat):
        X, true_labels, Xm = make_fake_data(fraction_missing=frac, n_clusters=5)
        labels, centroids, X_hat = kmeans_missing(Xm, n_clusters=5)
        any_missing = np.any(~np.isfinite(Xm), 1)
        scores[0, i, j] = adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels, true_labels)
        scores[1, i, j] = adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels[any_missing],
                                                     true_labels[any_missing])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
scores_all, scores_missing = scores
ax.errorbar(fraction * 100, scores_all.mean(-1),
            yerr=scores_all.std(-1), label='All labels')
ax.errorbar(fraction * 100, scores_missing.mean(-1),
            yerr=scores_missing.std(-1),
            label='Labels with missing values')
ax.set_xlabel('% missing values')
ax.set_ylabel('Adjusted mutual information')
ax.legend(loc='best', frameon=False)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_xlim(-5, 100)
```

[image]

#### Update:

In fact, after a quick Google search it seems that what I've come up with above is pretty much the same as the *k*-POD algorithm for K-means clustering of missing data [(Chi, Chi & Baraniuk, 2016)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.7013.pdf).

Comment: Ok, this seems to be very close to what I had (slightly confused) in my mind. Thank you, I will try this. And thank you for the hint on the k-POD algorithm.

Comment: Any reason two groups flipped colors in the plot? or was that accidental?

Comment: @zelite The colors are determined by the cluster labels, which are set in an arbitrary order. Actually, it might be clearer to use the same set of labels for the original and imputed data. I might change it if I have time later today.

Comment: @ali_m, don't you need to do the second scatter plot using `c=labels_hat` and not `c=labels`?

Comment: @Cupitor That would be cheating :-). If I colored the imputed points according to `labels_hat` then the colors of the points within each blob would be guaranteed to be homogeneous. Also, because the labels for the inferred clusters are initialized randomly, the mapping between "true" and imputed cluster labels is arbitrary. For example, the top cluster might have label 3 in the original data, but label 1 in the imputed data. This would result in the colors of the blobs being randomly shuffled, which makes the figure harder to interpret.

Comment: Ahh... Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: @ali_m one more question. When I am using your code, I am getting an error that since the centroids are set manually K-means mini batches will run only for a single step. Does that mean the iteration runs for a single step, and is that indeed why you loop over max_iter and do the convergence check yourself out of K-means function? Thank you!

Comment: @ali_m, one more note is that your code crashes when the dimensions is larger than say 30 (i.e. `n_features=30`. Do you have any idea why?)

Comment: @Cupitor 1) Yes, `KMeans` does minibatches over cluster initializations. If we set the initial cluster centroids explicitly then the `n_jobs` argument does nothing. 2) I guess you're probably just running out of memory. I'd have to dig into sklearn's source code to know for sure, but most k-means implementations use *O(n + kd)* memory, where *n* is the number of samples, *k* is the number of clusters to find, and *d* is the dimensionality of the feature space. So the memory requirements will increase multiplicatively with the number of features.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different algorithm that I use. Instead of replacing the missing values the values are ignored and in order to capture the differences between missing and non-missing i impliment missing dummies.

Compared to Alis algorithm it seems is easier for observations with missing observatons to jump from class to class. Since I do not fill the missing values.

I fortunely did not have the time to compare using Ali's beautiful code, but feel free to do it (I might do it when I get the time) and contribute to the discussion about the best method.

```
import numpy as np
class kmeans_missing(object):
    def __init__(self,potential_centroids,n_clusters):
        #initialize with potential centroids
        self.n_clusters=n_clusters
        self.potential_centroids=potential_centroids
    def fit(self,data,max_iter=10,number_of_runs=1):
        n_clusters=self.n_clusters
        potential_centroids=self.potential_centroids

        dist_mat=np.zeros((data.shape[0],n_clusters))
        all_centroids=np.zeros((n_clusters,data.shape[1],number_of_runs))

        costs=np.zeros((number_of_runs,))
        for k in range(number_of_runs):
            idx=np.random.choice(range(potential_centroids.shape[0]), size=(n_clusters), replace=False)
            centroids=potential_centroids[idx]
            clusters=np.zeros(data.shape[0])
            old_clusters=np.zeros(data.shape[0])
            for i in range(max_iter):
                #Calc dist to centroids
                for j in range(n_clusters):
                    dist_mat[:,j]=np.nansum((data-centroids[j])**2,axis=1)
                #Assign to clusters
                clusters=np.argmin(dist_mat,axis=1)
                #Update clusters
                for j in range(n_clusters):
                    centroids[j]=np.nanmean(data[clusters==j],axis=0)
                if all(np.equal(clusters,old_clusters)):
                    break # Break when to change in clusters
                if i==max_iter-1:
                    print('no convergence before maximal iterations are reached')
                else:
                    clusters,old_clusters=old_clusters,clusters

            all_centroids[:,:,k]=centroids
            costs[k]=np.mean(np.min(dist_mat,axis=1))
        self.costs=costs
        self.cost=np.min(costs)
        self.best_model=np.argmin(costs)
        self.centroids=all_centroids[:,:,self.best_model]
        self.all_centroids=all_centroids
    def predict(self,data):
        dist_mat=np.zeros((data.shape[0],self.n_clusters))
        for j in range(self.n_clusters):
            dist_mat[:,j]=np.nansum((data-self.centroids[j])**2,axis=1)
        prediction=np.argmin(dist_mat,axis=1)
        cost=np.min(dist_mat,axis=1)
        return prediction,cost
```

Here is an example on how  though it might be usefull.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from kmeans_missing import *

def make_fake_data(fraction_missing, n_clusters=5, n_samples=1500,
                   n_features=2, seed=None):
    # complete data
    gen = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    X, true_labels = make_blobs(n_samples, n_features, n_clusters,
                                random_state=gen)
    # with missing values
    missing = gen.rand(*X.shape) < fraction_missing
    Xm = np.where(missing, np.nan, X)
    return X, true_labels, Xm
X, true_labels, X_hat = make_fake_data(fraction_missing=0.3, n_clusters=3, seed=0)
X_missing_dummies=np.isnan(X_hat)
n_clusters=3
X_hat = np.concatenate((X_hat,X_missing_dummies),axis=1)
kmeans_m=kmeans_missing(X_hat,n_clusters)
kmeans_m.fit(X_hat,max_iter=100,number_of_runs=10)
print(kmeans_m.costs)
prediction,cost=kmeans_m.predict(X_hat)

for i in range(n_clusters):
    print([np.mean((prediction==i)*(true_labels==j)) for j in range(3)],np.mean((prediction==i)))
```

--EDIT--

In this example the occurrences of missing values are completly random and when that is the case. Not adding the missing value dummies preforms better, since missing value dummies in that case is noise. Not including them would also be the correct thing to do in order to compare with Ali's algorithm.