# How do I handle null values in cluster analysis?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, nan, k-means

I am into fintech business and I have customer level data like below:

| Customer ID | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 0 | NaN | 5 |
| 2 | NaN | 10 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | -100 | -100 | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 10 | -60 | 0 | 100 |
| 5 | 20 | NaN | -20 | NaN |

In the above data, the rows represent customer unique ID, columns represent the specific day of the year and the values represent the net of credit and debit on that specific day.

For example, for customer `ID = 1` on `day1`, the `credit = 100` and `debit = 50` therefore net is 50. Zero means `credit = debit` on that day.

`NaN` in my data simply shows that on that specific day, the customer neither did any credit or debit transactions from the app, and this knowledge is important to me. Let `NaN` be the instance of **NO INTERACTION**.

Now my question is how do I tell K-Means in scikit-learn python to treat NaN values like No Interaction? I don't want to eliminate `NaN` values. I also don't want to replace `NaN` values with mean or median values. `NaN` values are additional information for me and how do I retain this information?

Comment: Maybe you can add for each day a columns that indicates whether there was interaction that day setting it to 1 if there was interaction and to 0 if there was no interaction. And for days without interaction you replace the nan values in the columns for net credit with 0 as there was zero net credit that day.

Comment: Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611465/python-scikit-learn-clustering-with-missing-data).

Answer (score 1):

The [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and other clustering methods using distance ([Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)) to calculate.

To calculate distance you need numbers and all thing must be quantitative.

Exactly, you must delete those or replace those NaN values with the best representative (median or mean or 0).

How do I decide?

Which customer do you think is closer to customer number 1?

customer 2, 3 or 4?

| Customer ID | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 0 | NaN | 5 |
| 2 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 3 | 50 | 0 | median | 5 |
| 4 | 50 | 0 | mean | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
df_no = df.replace(np.nan, 'no', regex=True)
```